# how to find the key of max value of a map in flutter?

Tags: flutter

This is the required map. I want the output to be neutral.

```
{anger: 0.0, contempt: 0.02, disgust: 0.0, fear: 0.0, happiness: 0.0, neutral: 0.978, sadness: 0.002, surprise: 0.0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map themap={"anger": 0.0, "contempt": 0.02, "disgust": 0.0, "fear": 2.0, "happiness": 0.0, "neutral": 0.978, "sadness": 0.002, "surprise": 0.0};

    var thevalue=0.0;
    var thekey;

    themap.forEach((k,v){
      if(v>thevalue) {
        thevalue = v;
        thekey = k;
      }
    });

    print (thekey);
```